# MCQ Quiz web-app via MySQL and JSPs

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

I am working on a Web Application(JSP) for conducting MCQ(Multiple Choice Questions) quizzes. All my questions are stored in the MySql Database under 'qna' table. There are 10 questions and subsequent choices in each. I want to create a quiz with timer per question and each question showing up on a fresh page (i.e, one question per page). Moreover I don't want to end up creating 10 JSPs' for 10 questions (That's absurd!!). How do I manage to access each question from the database and keep displaying them one by one. (Note: All in one JSP). Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use AJAX here.

1. Create a single page to show question.
2. Fetch All Questions and Option details once and show them one by one, or you can fetch them one by one using ajax based on your test ID. You can use **display** property of css to show and hide them.
3. Once answered any question call some ajax code to save and show next question.

Kindly try this approach and come up with some code if you face any issue.
To get more idea you can checkout aptitude test sample here- [www.technicalbaba.com/app/all-online-tests](http://www.technicalbaba.com/app/all-online-tests)